# Broadcasting event error in Laravel 5.1 using Redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket, redis

I've started to use Laravel 5.1 and its pretty awesome, just wanted to play around with the new 'Broadcasting Event' feature by using NodeJs as the server and Redis as the driver following the guide here: http://blog.nedex.io/laravel-5-1-broadcasting-events-using-redis-driver-socket-io/. When i fire an event which implements the ShouldBroadcast interface i receive an error: 
"Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:4365]"

4365 - is the port which the server is running on (listening in that port). Do you have any idea why does it happend?

I tried also to use Redis directly:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->publish('test-channel', 'msg');
```

Got the same result, "Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:4365]".

socket.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.payload);
});

http.listen(4365, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 4365');
});
```

config\database.php:

```
 'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 4365,
            'database' => 0,
            'timeout'  => 100,
        ],

    ],
```

Tried to change the defulat timeout, set it to 0, -1 or >10
Also tried to disable Xdebug in php.ini the problem persists.

I made some debug deeply to the code trying to undertand what might cause this problem and it fails in class: Predis\Connection\StreamConnection

```
public function read()
    {
        $socket = $this->getResource();
        $chunk = fgets($socket);

    if ($chunk === false || $chunk === '') {
            $this->onConnectionError('Error while reading line from the server.');
        }
...
```

chunk is false why?
And why does the redis client is trying to read data from the server, for my understanding it should 'publish' data to the server, means it should write (broadcast) not read..

Comment: Are you sure Redis is running on 4365? The standard port is 6379.

Comment: I think its configurable, look at the script I added, i changed the port and also my nodejs server is configure to that port. If the port in laravel and in the nodejs script are different I get different error (connection error) so I think it makes a connection but has issues to read from the stream dont you think?

Comment: Hang on, you're running your node app on 4365. Laravel's Redis functionality expects to be talking to a Redis server, not your Node app. You need Laravel to publish to Redis, not Node. The Node app should listen to Redis.

Comment: How do I publish to redis, whats wrong with the code? You see in socket.js file I create new instance of redis and subsctibe channels, and in laravel side I create redis client with that port and when I publish I do it to the exact same channel

Comment: You've created a Redis **client**. You need a Redis **server** that both Node and Laravel communicate with.

Comment: And how do I do that? Do i need both node and redis servers?

Comment: Yes, Redis is a separate technology. You'll need to install Redis and get it running.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a misunderstanding of what [Redis](http://redis.io/) is and does.

> Redis is an open source, BSD licensed, advanced **key-value cache** and **store**.

It is often used for interprocess communication (IPC) with it's nice PUBLISH and SUBSCRIBE commands.

So with Laravel and Node, Redis enables the communication between the permanently running process of Node and Laravel. Laravel publishs its events to Redis and Node subscribes to the specific channel of Redis. Here you **can** emit a message via socket connection most likely the channel names are the same.

To get this all working you have to to the following ([very well explained in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events)):

1. Install Redis on your system. Standard Port is 6379.
2. Set dependency in composer.json: predis/predis ~1.0
3. Configure Redis in config/database.php.
4. Set Redis in config/broadcasting.php as Default Broadcaster.
5. Set your Default Queue Driver in config/queue.php. (Note: Event publishing doesn't work for me if I set Redis as Queue Driver. But direct publishing is working `Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));`. Maybe its a Bug?
6. Now you can create and fire events that implement `ShouldBroadcast`. For testing purposes you can use this: `Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));`

Now its time to switch over to Node:
Your code of socket.js looks good, assumed Redis is on Port 6379. If Node is running locally you can connect to your Node server in your Browser like so: `localhost:4365`.

Here's my code testing Node and Socket.io in front- and backend:

**socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


redis.subscribe('test-channel', function () {
    console.log('Redis: test-channel subscribed');
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Redis: Message on ' + channel + ' received!');
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel, message.payload)
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket.IO</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages">
    <li>Hardcoded Message</li>
</ul>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on("test-channel", function(message) {
        console.log(message);
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(message));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the above error, after x seconds (not straight away), then you need to set the read write timeout in your database.php config file.

If this is intended to run as a background task, something like the following will work:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => '6379',
        'database' => 0,
        'read_write_timeout' => -1 
    ],

],
```